# How does one pull an API environment variable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, environment-variables, google-places-api

Implementing in rails and only running locally for the time being.

Using I have a google API server key for google places that is... lets say... "abc123"

When I use a url just to see with a url like:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=abc123
```

it pulls information.

When I type env from mac terminal I have a value listed that is :

```
PLACES_API=abc123
```

when I run the code filling in the literal key:

```
@client = GooglePlaces::Client.new("abc123")
```

it works fine.

HOWEVER, when I try and pull this in using

```
@client = GooglePlaces::Client.new(ENV['PLACES_API'])
```

it errors out and when I try to puts ENV['PLACES_API'] it is blank.

I am assuming I am not using the env variable correctly, but now I want to know what I am doing wrong and how to use the environmental variable.

Comment: If you `puts ENV` do you see other environment variables?

Comment: If I puts ENV, it just logs a "ENV" - if I run the each method on it and puts each of the elements, yes... it prints out many of the things, but not my variable!

Comment: Sorry. I didn't realize `ENV` had defined it's `to_s` method to just output `ENV`. In any event, just to confirm, if you execute `ruby -e "puts ENV.has_key?('PLACES_API')" do you get `true` or `false`?

Comment: This returns a 'true'

Comment: I just added another test env variable and ran the each loop. It also did not print out. It is as though I am actually setting the variable (and have done from both the project root and the app/controllers dir), but the application is not reading from where I am setting it!

Comment: I would say that your setting the variables, but setting them to be empty.  You can `puts ENV.inspect` to see exactly what keys are present.  How are you setting the environment variables? And what do you get with the following command line: `PLACES_API=abc123 ruby -e "puts ENV['PLACES_API']"`?

Comment: absolutely they are be set to nil within the application or console puts ENV['PLACES_API'] yields nil. If I run ENV.inspect it shows the previously set env variables, but it does not show PLACES_API or a new test one I added. From the cl, if I type env... it does show. The rails environment isn't seeing the new additions.  Lovely problem for a Sunday morning!  ;)

Comment: So when you say that `ENV.inspect` from within Rails does not show `PLACES_API` do you mean the key is not present or that the key is present and the value is `nil` or the empty string?  Have you `grep`d for PLACES_API in your project to make sure it's not appearing in environment files, etc?

Comment: When I ENV.inspect from within Rails, the key value pair is not present at all... as though it does not exist at all.  PLACES_API=abc123 ruby -e "puts ENV['PLACES_API']" results in returning abc123. The only place in the project directory that contains PLACES_API is where I am trying to print it out.

Comment: This still perplexes me... and is a rabbit hole I really kind of want to continue down given infinite time...  but I included the figaro gem and now I am golden.

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION 1**

If you are using `ENV['PLACES_API']` in your code then before you start rails server you have to export the key. In your terminal run `export PLACES_API="api key"` and then start the server.

**OPTION 2 (A better way to handle secret keys )**

create a file `gmap.yaml` inside `config` directory with the following code

```
development:
  secret: "api key"
test:
  secret: "api key"
production:
  secret: "api key"
```

Now create a new file `gmap.rb` inside `config/initializars` directory with the following code

```
PLACES_API = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/gmap.yml")[::Rails.env]
```

Now you can access the key with

```
@client = GooglePlaces::Client.new(PLACES_API['secret'])
```

Comment: can you share the error? Also if you are using the second option you need to restart your rails server so that rails can load the key from initializer